# Compare an ICollection members with itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, time-complexity, icollection

Is there any cheapest way to compare an ICollection with itself.

Here is my code:

```
        public IEnumerable<Pet> speciesChecker()
        {
            foreach (Pet pet in _pets)
            {
                bool wantedSpecies = true;
                foreach (Pet pet2 in _pets)
                {
                    if (pet2 != pet && pet.Species == pet2.Species)
                    {
                        wantedSpecies = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (wantedSpecies) yield return pet;
            }
        }
```

What is the time complexity of my code, all I know is this that it is less than O(N^2) and if I'll remove 'break' from inner foreach loop, the time complexity will be O(N^2). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Is the purpose of this code to find all pets where there is no pets of the same species?

Comment: So what you want is to return all Pets in your collection such that no other Pet has the same Species?

Comment: @Mathias, yes exactly. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let `n` is the length of `_pets collection`

number of required steps with break:

```
1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2 =n^2/2 + n/2 = O(n^2) (for each pet in _pets);
```

There are two simple rules how to calculate O from wiki:

1. If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest
   growth rate is kept, and all others omitted.
2. If f(x) is a product of several factors, any constants (terms in
   the product that do not depend on x) are omitted.

number of required steps without break:

```
n+n+n+...+n = n^2 = O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it:

```
var q = list.GroupBy (l => l.Species)
          .Where (l => l.ElementAtOrDefault(1) == null)
          .Select (l => l.Key)
```

`GroupBy` will use HashSet internally so O(N)
`ElementAtOrDefault(1)` will only need to move the enumerator one step so will **not** be O(n)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that this code does the same thing. In that case, this is an O(N) algorithm. The trick is to store the pets in a dictionary indexed by species.

```
    public IEnumerable<Pet> speciesChecker()
    {
        var species = new Dictionary<Species, List<Pet>>();
        foreach (Pet pet in _pets)
        {
            // create the list if it doesn't exist
            if (!species.ContainsKey(pet.Species))
                species[pet.Species] = new List<Pet>();
            species[pet.Species].Add(pet);
        }

        // foreach species, if there is only one pet of that species, then return it
        foreach (var speciesPets in species.Values)
        {
            if (speciesPets.Count() == 1)
                yield return speciesPets.First();
        }

        yield break;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need the lists in the dictionary? Maybe I'm reading this wrong but it looks like you never have more than one element per list.

Comment: @ehdv that's exactly the point. The idea is to group the elements per species. He needs only the pets that belong to groups of 1 element.

Comment: Yep, I misread what the code's trying to accomplish. Your solution definitely works, but unless there's a *very* compelling efficiency argument, LINQ does the job more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like the following, which should also be O(N):

```
public IEnumerable<Pet> speciesChecker ()
{
    _pets.GroupBy (p => p.Species)
         .Select (g => new List<Pet> (g))
         .Where (l => l.Count == 1)
         .SelectMany (l => l);
}
```

The extra `Select (g => new List<Pet> (g))` *may* be superfluous, but I believe that will help avoid iterating the whole grouping logic a second time, which I believe would result in O(N^2) .

**Edit:** Good comment from Magnus about the List constructor operating in O(n) defeating the purpose...

How about:

```
public IEnumerable<Pet> speciesChecker ()
{
    var groups = _pets.GroupBy (p => p.Species);

    foreach (var grp in _pets.GroupBy (p => p.Species))
    using (var e = grp.GetEnumerator ()) {
        if (!e.MoveNext ())
            continue;

        var first = e.Current;

        if (e.MoveNext ())
            continue;

        yield return first;
    }
}
```

I *think* this is as optimized as you can get, and will work in O(n). We avoid using the `IEnumerable<T>.Any ()` or `IEnumerable<T>.Count ()` extension method as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is not adding all the items in g to the list an O(n) operation?

Comment: @Magnus Indeed. Editing with an updated version that might work better.